# Вывести в QMessageBox значения из массива. PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

У меня есть массив `results` со строками и есть метод:

```
QMessageBox.information(self, "Submit", "Press Ok", QMessageBox.Ok)
```

где вместо строки `"Press Ok"` хочу передать строки из массива.

Каким образом это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто сджойнь строки - получится одна. Например через перевод строки:

```
msg = '\n'.join(results)
QMessageBox.information(self, "Submit", msg, QMessageBox.Ok)
```